# Python3 in terminal

Tags: macos, python-3.x, terminal, segmentation-fault

I am on OSX 10.6.8, and python 2.7.5 is the default in my terminal. When I use python 3 by typing in `"python3"` and try to import something, it returns a segmentation fault. What is this, and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Example:

```
>>> import heapq
[1]    567 segmentation fault  python3
```

Also, it is recommended for me to have python 3 as the default on my system? If so, how can I make that happen?

Comment: To use Python 3 as a defult one you must change the PATH to Python 3 directory. And with this segmentation fault… I've installed Python 3 using brew and everything was fine. Try reinstalling using brew.

Comment: Try launching python3.3 maybe there is a problem with your environment variables, like a symbolic link broken (e.g your python executables doesn't know where to find the libs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be comment on your post since I don't think I can really give a true answer to all of your questions right away, but I don't have the reputation to do that, so here I go.

Firstly, it is a little strange you are getting segmentation faults instead of location errors (i.e. the module you want to import can't be found). I think this suggests there is something wrong with your installation, and the simplest way to deal with this would be to try re-installing. Which leads to the question, how did you install python3? For the new installation, I would recommend using a package manager for OSX like MacPorts or Homebrew. Although they have a slight learning curve to them, they will greatly simplify your life in the future as you will never need to worry about the dependencies of packages again (and you can be more confident in the installation process in general).

A quick way of making python3 the "default" (i.e. what "$ python" will give you from a command line) is to just make a symbolic link to python3 wherever the executables are. For me:

$ ln -s /opt/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python

(Of course, python3.3 might be in the same directory as your other python executables, but this doesn't change things).